# Linq with different data types

Tags: c#, linq

I am getting this error `The type of one of the expression in the join clause is incorrect Type`. I believe its because the different data types. In the Customer table CustomerId is a bigint but in the CustmerGroupXref CustomerId is just an int. Is there a way to get this working in linq? I dont want to change the database field type.

```
var query1 =  (from c in db.Customers
               join cgx in db.CustomerGroupXrefs on c.CustomerId  equals cgx.CustomerId)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why don't you want to change the type? What happens when you want to reference a customer that has an ID too big for `int`?

Comment: I just didnt want to make a database change at this time just wanted to know if there was another way to do it

Comment: Why are the sizes of the Customer IDs different?  Maybe you should make the Customer ID a string instead of a integer so you do not have the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you could try a cast:

```
var query1 =  (from c in db.Customers
               join cgx in db.CustomerGroupXrefs 
                   on c.CustomerId equals (long)cgx.CustomerId)
```

or a conversion:

```
var query1 =  (from c in db.Customers
               join cgx in db.CustomerGroupXrefs 
                   on c.CustomerId equals Convert.ToInt64(cgx.CustomerId))
```

But I would recommend just making the types equal if it's intended to be a foreign key - you run the risk of having IDs in the customer table that can't be referenced in the group table.